# unable to stop function from returning early using async/await

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use async/await to call an API and wait for results before iterating through multi-level objects/arrays and extracting relevant data. The problem I am having is I cannot access the data outside of the forLoop. See below:

```
const gameStrings = ['LAA-NYM', 'LAA-TB', 'NYY-HOU'];

const startingPlayers = [];

gameStrings.forEach(async function(element, i) {

let query = await fetch('fakeapi.com', element);

  query.gamestartinglineup.teamLineup.forEach(b => b.actual.starter.forEach(c => {

    if (c.player) {
      const player = {
        id: c.player.FirstName + '-' + c.player.LastName + '-' + c.player.ID
      }
      startingPlayers.push(player);
    }

  }));
```

> startingPlayers ['Mookie-Betts-10456', '...', '...'] <-- Within forEach, data is here!

```
})
```

> startingPlayers [] <-- Outside of forEach it's an empty array...

Comment: this seems not to be all of the relevant code (due to there is no access to the array out of the **3!** loops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `for(let i of items){...` instead of `.forEach(t => {...` loop when working with `async`

```
const gameStrings = ['LAA-NYM', 'LAA-TB', 'NYY-HOU'];

const startingPlayers = [];

for (let element of gameStrings) {

    let query = await fetch('fakeapi.com', element);

    query.gamestartinglineup.teamLineup.forEach(b => b.actual.starter.forEach(c => {

        if (c.player) {
            const player = {
                id: c.player.FirstName + '-' + c.player.LastName + '-' + c.player.ID
            }
            startingPlayers.push(player);
        }

    }));
}
```

Comment: Could you show me what you mean. It's not immediately making sense to me. It took me two days to iterate through the API's response correctly with the current code.

Comment: @Chris check it now

Comment: Fantastic... that did it. Curious why the forEach there was a problem but the further nested ones are ok?

Comment: the inner await will mess up `.forEach`'s